# Using function arguments and this in same method

Tags: typescript

I have a function in JavaScript that uses both `this` and captures the arguments:

```
var Watcher = function() {
  var callbacks = [];
  var currentValue = null;

  this.watch = function (callback) {
    callbacks.push(callback);
    if (currentValue) {
      callback.apply(null, currentValue);
    }
  };
  this.notify = function() {
    currentValue = arguments;
    for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
      callbacks[i].apply(null, arguments);
    }
  };
}
```

I want to change this to a TypeScript class. What I've come up with, is:

```
class Watcher {
  private currentValue: any[] = null;
  private callbacks: Function[] = [];

  watch = (callback: Function) => {
    this.callbacks.push(callback);
    if (this.currentValue) {
      callback.apply(null, this.currentValue);
    }
  }
  // cannot access arguments
  notify = () => {
    this.currentValue = /*arguments?*/;
    for (var callback of this.callbacks) {
      callback.apply(null, /*arguments?*/);
    }
  }
  // cannot acces this
  notify() {
    /*this?*/.currentValue = arguments;
    for (var callback of /*this?*/.callbacks) {
      callback.apply(null, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

How do I make a function where I can both use the `this` reference to get to my fields, *and* the arguments passed into my function?

Comment: You can access this in the second notify-method, don't worry.

Comment: From what I understand, that might break depending on how the notify method gets called, and TypeScript works around that by using the closure syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an arrow function that uses a ["Rest" parameter](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-rest-parameters) to capture a boundless number of optional parameters:

```
notify = (...args) => {
  this.currentValue = args;
  for (var callback of this.callbacks) {
    callback.apply(null, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Make the implicit args explicit. Right, why didn't I think of that?